# On which jQuery versions will my code run?

Tags: javascript, jquery, version

I have a piece of jQuery code I wrote using the latest version, 2.1.4.
My script is going to be loaded and run on many clients websites. those websites have different versions of jQuery loaded, or not loading jQuery at all.

I want to implement some logic saying "If there's no jQuery, or jQuery version is lower than x, load my own jQuery before running my script."

How can I check on which jQuery versions my code works well, and on which it fails?

Comment: `How can I check on which jQuery versions my code works well, and on which it fails` by far the easiest is to try it on those versions and see. If you want to actually research it, then you'd need to lookup the change logs for each different version and check for methods/properties which you rely on which have had breaking changes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to/should read through the documentations or the patch notes. If you're not using a lot of jQuery, it might not be necessary unless they don't load it themselves. Depending on the type of methods you use, it might not vary from the versions, since I can't believe they would be some of the more primitive versions

Answer (score 0):

To check if jquery is present or not:

```
if(!window.jQuery){
   // jQuery Not present or Not loaded uptil now.
}
```

To fetch the jQuery version:

```
var _ver = jQuery.fn.jquery;
```

And to check if your application will work with what minimum version you should do a bit of research and check by including different versions of jQuery one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Like void said, check if jquery is loaded and what version is loaded, load your own if necessary:

```
<script>
if(!window.jQuery || jquery.fn.jquery < 'minimal_version')
{
   var script = document.createElement('script');
   script.type = "text/javascript";
   script.src = "path/to/jQuery";
   document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

var jQueryNeeded = 2.1;

```
if (!window.jQuery || (window.jQuery && parseFloat(window.jQuery.fn.jquery) < jQueryNeeded)) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    // you can update this link according to the path where jquery is stored
    script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/'+ jQueryNeeded +'/jquery.min.js';
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    // better to apend to header since you need to be sure that jquery is loaded before your script
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

About loading jQuery, you can read here why is ok to [use a CDN](http://www.sitepoint.com/7-reasons-to-use-a-cdn/)

Usually is not the best way to load js in header, but since your scripts are loaded in footer (it should!), better append jquery in header to be sure that the order is followed as it should.